# Something like "table-layout:fixed" but only for one table-column

Tags: html, css, text, html-table

I have the problem that I have a very big value inside one cell:

> 43003A005C00570069006E0064006F00770073005C00730079007300740065006D00330032005C0076006D00470075006500730074004C00690062002E0064006C006C00000043003A005C00500072006F006700720061006D002000460069006C00650073005C0056004D0077006100720065005C0056004D007700610072006500200054006F006F006C0073005C0076006D0053007400610074007300500072006F00760069006400650072005C00770069006E00360034005C0076006D0053007400610074007300500072006F00760069006400650072002E0064006C006C000000

What it does is that the whole table gets bigger than it should.

I now added `table-layout:fixed` to the table, the whole table gets resized, not only the column with this value.

What I want is that all other columns have their size they need, but only that the last one should be rearranged (use multiple lines).

```
/**
  * Returns a table with the values from a query
  */
function tableizeQryRes($arr) {
  $isFirst=true;
  $tbl = '<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="2" frame="box" rules="all" style="table-layout:fixed">';
  foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    //echo $key;
    if ($isFirst) {
      $tblHeader = '<tr align="center" valign="middle"><td></td>';
      $tblBody = '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td>';
      foreach ($val as $sub_key => $sub_val) {
        if ($sub_key == "Msg") {
          $tblHeader .= '<td style="word-wrap:break-word; width:40%">'.$sub_key.'</td>';
          $tblBody .= '<td style="word-wrap:break-word; width:40%">'.$sub_val.'</td>';
        } else {
          $tblHeader .= '<td>'.$sub_key.'</td>';
          $tblBody .= '<td>'.$sub_val.'</td>';
        }
      }
      $tblHeader .= '</tr>';
      $tblBody .= '</tr>';
      $tbl .= $tblHeader;
      $tbl .= $tblBody;
      $isFirst=false;
    } else {
      $tbl .= '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td>';
      foreach ($val as $sub_key => $sub_val) {
        if ($sub_key == "Msg") {
          $tbl .= '<td style="word-wrap:break-word; width:40%">'.$sub_val.'</td>';
        } else {
          $tbl .= '<td>'.$sub_val.'</td>';
        }
      }
      $tbl .= '</tr>';
    }
  }
  $tbl .= '</table>';

  echo '<div style="max-width:100%; hyphens:auto">';
  echo $tbl;
  echo '<br/>';
  echo '<br/>';
  echo '</div>';
}
```

If I add sth. like `style="word-wrap:break-word; width:40%"` and `table-layout:fixed` the other cells get also fixed and don't adjust anymore.

**BTW.:** All the columns are variable in length (and there are about 150 000 rows). The first 5 columns are small, only the 6. one contains a message, sometimes with a space, somethimes without.

Comment: please Show you live code and what You want

Comment: Ok, I added the code now. ;)

Comment: try adding id or class to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS3 text module allows you to break long words so that they wrap around multiple lines using `word-wrap: break-word`.  However, what can happen in some cases is that there
is a large white gap to the right before a long word since a long non-breaking word
starts on a new line, even though short words can follow the long word.

One way around this is to to use `white-space: pre-wrap` and `word-break: break-all` which will prevent long white spaces from forming right before a long non-breaking word.

However, the down side is that some small words may wrap around onto a second line.

You have two options, the `word-wrap` method which can leave large gaps before a long non-breaking word, or the `whtie-space/word-break` method that can leave some small words wrapped
around two lines.

I think this is as far as you can go with CSS3. Anything else will require some JavaScript
assisted solution.

```css
table {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
table td {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table td.wrapping {
  width: 350px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-all
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a regular table cell with some text</td>
    <td class="wrapping">some short words in the text andaverylongword to fill up the line 43003A005C00570069006E0064006F00770073005C00730079007300740065006D00330032005C0076006D00470075006500730074004C00690062002E0064006C006C00000043003A005C00500072006F006700720061006D002000460069006C00650073005C0056004D0077006100720065005C0056004D007700610072006500200054006F006F006C0073005C0076006D0053007400610074007300500072006F00760069006400650072005C00770069006E00360034005C0076006D0053007400610074007300500072006F00760069006400650072002E0064006C006C000000 and a few words at the end
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thx!, now the size of the cells looks good, but like that it also "breaks" words which shouldn't be split (because there are spaces before and after).

Comment: I reworked the solution, indeed, `word-wrap` is the critical property to apply AND it needs to be added to a wrapping block element within the table cell.

Comment: Yes, tried `word-wrap` and `break-word`, both look differently "not good"... ;)

Comment: Ooh, sry, this makes totally no sense what I said... Like you mentioned it looks good apart from, that I don't know before the result is there, how many % to take: `table td.wrapping { width: 30%; }`

Comment: There are two ways of doing this, my method and the other one posted by @w3d Both have shortcomings so it is up to you do decided, based on your content, which might work best and which will be less confusing for the people looking at the page.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! ;) So there is no solution which does 100% what I want to do, apart from programming sth myself (which would take probably too much time to execute which so much rows ^^).

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `word-wrap:break-word` on the containing element.

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syraw0m1/)

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Column One</td>
        <td>Column Two</td>
        <td class="wrap">43003A005C00570069006Eetc...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}

.wrap {
    width:40%;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: <td style="word-wrap:break-word">'.$sub_val.'</td>

Thanks! ;) But this doesn't work.

Comment: If you add it to the table cell you'll still need to keep your `table-layout:fixed` on the table. And set some widths. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Ok, thx! If I add sth. like `style="word-wrap:break-word; width:40%"` and `table-layout:fixed` the other cells get also fixed and don't adjust anymore.

Comment: Is the content variable and needs to flex? In that case I would suggest `word-break` (as in Marc's answer), although you've mentioned that there are also _spaces_ in this cell? As you've found this is also not going to be optimal.

Comment: All the cells are variable in length (about 150 000 rows). But the first 5 are small, only the 6. one contains a message, sometimes with a space, somethimes without. But `word-break` doesn't do the job... :(

Comment: @Dobi w3d is very close, you need to apply the `.wrap` properties to a block level elmenent within the table-cell, see my updated post.

Comment: @MarcAudet What's the reason for the block-level container (eg. `div`)? Browser compatibility with older browsers? My example (without the `div`) appears to work OK in the latest browsers?

Comment: You are absolutely right, the `div` is not strictly necessary. I was thinking of some other application in which the table layout was not fixed. +1 to you!

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! ;) So there is no solution which does 100% what I want to do, apart from programming sth myself (which would take probably too much time to execute which so much rows ^^).

Answer (score 0):

On firefox you have to use "max-width" instead of just "width" or it will be just ignored on a table with "layout-table: auto".

So, if you don't want to use "layout-table: auto" you can just assign a class like this to the column you want to limit in size

```
.wrap {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```